# Get User who created list item

Tags: alert, 2007, email

In `IAlertNotifyHandler` implementation I need name of the user who created/add the current item/document to the list (for which this alert is being sent). What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your OnNotification method you can access the list item with code similar to this.

```
public bool OnNotification(SPAlertHandlerParams ahp)

    {

      SPSite site = new SPSite(ahp.siteUrl+ahp.webUrl);

      SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

      SPList list=web.Lists[ahp.a.ListID];

      SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(ahp.eventData[0].itemId);

      String user = item("Author");

     }
```

Not sure on your requirements but you may need to add some additional code to then get a domain\username if this is what you require.

**Note:**  This is sub-optimal code to highlight only the code needed to get the list item.  I know there are dispose issues here.

Comment: @Charles I'm usint `SPFieldUserValue oUser = item["Created By"] as SPFieldUserValue;`. Will this pose a problem?

Comment: Not if it works no.  Are you getting an appropriate value back?

Comment: Remember to dispose SPSite/SPWeb you create yourself

Comment: I did mention that in my last note, but I suppose its worth another mention in the comments.

Comment: Definitely @Anders and @Charles i'm opening site and web using `using` constructs

Comment: @Charles is it `item("Author")` or `item["Author"]`?

Comment: square brackets for C# apologies  I have a VB head on most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

No Need for Code or anything, Add the Fields Created By and Modified By and you see all.

Comment: He needs the info in C#, not in the GUI